# SQL: Records on same day but different time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sample data:

```
2015-10-09 17:06:54
2015-01-05 11:04:12
2015-01-05 11:04:13
2015-01-09 14:52:19
```

Hi, I am trying to get a list of records of date + time with a condition: If same date, get the earliest record.

I know this can be easily done by substr() to only the date, but I do need the time too.

Please see the data above: I do not want the 3rd record down because it is a duplicate date but a later time.

How should I do this? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Then what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data *and* desired results in the question.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your suggestion. I did do that with the image attached, but I'm a new user it is a link on top 'Example'. That is the sample data.

Comment: Since you mention using SUBSTR( ) to get the date part does that imply the date data is stored in a VARCHAR2 column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MS SQL 2005+`, you can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
      RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(DateTime_Column AS DATE) ORDER BY DateTime_Column DESC) AS R
   FROM Your_Table) AS Tb
WHERE R = 1
```

If you want to select 1 row for each day, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`

In Oracle, you can change `CAST(DateTime_Column AS DATE)` to `TRUNC(DateTime_Column)`

Answer (score 0):

This will display row with later date_time for a specific date.

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM 
        table T1 INNER JOIN table T2 
         ON  DATE(T1.date_time) = DATE(T2.date_time)
         AND T1.date_time > T2.date_time GROUP BY DATE(T1.date_time)
```

Hope this helps..